# SetDate() behaves weirdly in datepicker modal

Tags: reactjs, date

I have a day picker in a datepicker modal I am writing in React with hooks. I want to display today's date in the middle and count backwards going up and forwards going down from today. I also need my dates to wrap to the next or previous month and start or end on the correct number of days. My html looks like this

```
    <div className={'dateField'} ref={dayRef}>
                    <div>{getDayNumber(-3)}</div>
                    <div>{getDayNumber(-2)}</div>
                    <div>{getDayNumber(-1)}</div>
                    {/* TODAY */}
                    <div>{date.getDate()}</div>
                    {/* END TODAY */}
                    <div>{getDayNumber(1)}</div>
                    <div>{getDayNumber(2)}</div>
                    <div>{getDayNumber(3)}</div>
                </div>
```

I have a getDayNumber function, but it behaves very strangely. It will count backwards, but not forwards, and sets today's date minus 1 as the same as today's date. I think this is because it is somehow switching to a 0 index count of days? How do I change this back into the day number?

```
const getDayNumber = (dayNumber) => {
    var newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - dayNumber));
    console.log('NEW DATE NUMBER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!', newDate.getDate());
    return newDate.getDate();
};
```

I also have an issue where passing different numbers into getDayNumber() doesn't work - I think this is because I am resetting the central date object with setDate()?:

const [ date, setMyDate ] = useState(new Date());

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the getDayNumber function to create a new Date first gets rid of the problem:

```
const getDayNumber = (dayNumber) => {
    var newDate = new Date();
    newDate.setDate(date.getDate() - dayNumber);
    console.log('NEW DATE NUMBER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!', newDate.getDate());
    return newDate.getDate();
};
```